# ReactJS Can't resolve 'react' in 'mini-create-react-context/dist/esm'

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem running `yarn start`.

```
/node_modules/mini-create-react-context/dist/esm/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/home/adenir/Área de trabalho/ProgrammingProjects/HRP/infernoapp/node_modules/mini-create-react-context/dist/esm'
```

I've tried to clear the cache, delete the `package-lock.json`, delete the `node-modules`, give the `yarn install` again and nothing resolves.

[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ursuy.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following command will resolve it:

```
npm i mini-create-react
```

mini-create -react is now read only but some packages still need it.